# How to specify tax in Gmail Schema.org markup?

Tags: gmail, schema.org

According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/order) I can specify tax with `priceSpecification`. And syntax must be for example something like this (delivery charge example):

```
"priceSpecification": [
    {
      "@type": "DeliveryChargeSpecification",
      "price": "10.00",
      "priceCurrency": "USD"
    }
]
```

The only problem is that there is no documentation about which `@type` for the "tax" must be specified, like in this example with delivery charge `DeliveryChargeSpecification`.

I tried to find it there and on Schema.org with no success. Any suggestions how is possible to specify tax charge information with Gmail markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vocabulary Schema.org provides three sub-types for the [`PriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/PriceSpecification) type:

- [`DeliveryChargeSpecification`](http://schema.org/DeliveryChargeSpecification)
- [`PaymentChargeSpecification`](http://schema.org/PaymentChargeSpecification)
- [`UnitPriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/UnitPriceSpecification)

Unless one of these applies in your case, you should use the parent type, 
[`PriceSpecification`](http://schema.org/PriceSpecification).

(If it’s about a price that *includes* VAT, you can use the corresponding type and its [`valueAddedTaxIncluded`](http://schema.org/valueAddedTaxIncluded) property, which Google [seems to support](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/types/PriceSpecification) for their email markup.)